# waitForNetwork без jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, xhr

у меня есть метод который проверяет есть ли активные запросы (XHR)

```
public void waitForNetwork() {
        int timeout_sec = 90;
        System.out.println("Checking active ajax calls:: ");
        JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = getBrowser().getJSExecuter();
        for (int i = 0; i < timeout_sec; i++) {
            Object numberOfAjaxConnections = jsDriver.executeScript("return jQuery.active");
            if (numberOfAjaxConnections instanceof Long) {
                Long n = (Long) numberOfAjaxConnections;
                System.out.print(" ajax calls: " + n + "...");
                if (n == 0L) {
                    break;}
            }getBrowser().pause(1000);
        }System.out.println();
}
```

тут "jQuery.active" возвращает 0 или 1. 
Но есть много сайтов без поддержки jQuery, как можно переписать этот метод без использования jQuery?
Пробовал проверить и подгрузить скриптом, но тогда все время возвращается 0 даже если есть активные процессы. Скрипт который я использовал:

```
if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    jq.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(jq);
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.active считает только запросы отправленые через jQuery. На сколько помню он вешает два обработчика на методы ajax. Один это AjaxStart и при нем увеличивает счетчик на 1 и AjaxStop, при нем соответственно уменьшает. Если вы хотите отлавливать активные запросы без привязки к jQuery, то я думаю вам нужно будет сделать что то подобное с XMLHttpRequest